# How do you exclusively get an input that is 2 decimal places for a float as a condition for a while loop in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm making a program that asks for input for the time. If I want the `float` input to be in this format, `9.24` which will be taken to mean `09:24`. How do I write a while loop that only allows for that kind of input? I am new to C++ programming so if you could dumb it down for me that would be great. Here's the while loop I have so far:

float time;
cout << "Please enter the time: ";`

```
while (cin >> time) 
{
    if ((time < 12.00) && (time > 0.00)) 
    {
        break; 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid input, please enter a valid time: ";
    }
}
```

*After this loop it asks if the time is in AM or PM but that's irrelevant to this.*

Comment: I don't think you want to be using floating point numbers for this at all. For instance C++ cannot represent `9.24` exactly as a float because of the underlying binary representation--it actually stores something like `9.2399997711181641` which is merely very close to it. I would suggest trying to read the time _as a string_ and asking yourself "what are the characteristics of a string that would count as valid input?"

Comment: You're asking for trouble by requiring input that isn't in the common format.  Using a decimal point between the hours and minutes is completely foreign to people, they'll want to use a colon instead.

Comment: @MarkRansom the decimal point between the hours and minutes is a requirement for this porgram so I can't use the colon, unfortunately.

Comment: It is unclear to me if you want the user to type in "9:24", "09:24", "9.24" or "09:24 = 9.24".

Comment: @Galik I want the user to type 9.24.

Comment: Just because the input looks like a float it's no reason to read it as float. For example read it as string, then parse it with a regex and get two integers from it. (Ab)using float will end badly sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple code with explanations that will be useful for you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    int hour, minute;
    std::string time; // we will read the time as string
    std::string delimiter = ":"; // we will split from this character
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::cout << "Please enter the time: (example=>09:24) ";

    while (std::cin >> time)
    {
        while ((pos = time.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
            hour = std::stoi(time); // we converted the hour information to integer
            time.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
            minute = std::stoi(time); // we converted the minute information to integer
        }
        if ((hour >= 0 && hour <= 12) && (minute >= 0 && minute < 60)) //necessary checks are made
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid input, please enter a valid time: ";
        }
    }
    std::string AmPm;
    std::cout << "AM or PM ?";
    while (std::cin >> AmPm) //We get the AM/PM information from the user as a string
    {
        if (AmPm =="AM" || AmPm=="PM") //necessary checks are made
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid input,please enter AM or PM ";
                
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Time is  " << hour << ":" << minute <<" " <<AmPm;
}
```

If you enter 9:24 and AM as test data, you will get the following output as output;

**Output =>** **Time is  9:24 AM**

If you wish, you can test the correctness of the delimiter entry in the code.

Note : `using namespace std;` =>> It's not good coding practice.

I wish you the best of luck.